Why the Closure Operation Is Unnecessary in Sanov's Theorem for Finite Alphabet
I am reading Dembo and Zeitouni's Large Deviations Techniques and Applications. The Sanov's Theorem in the book is represented as following:
Let $\Sigma$ be a finite alphabet and $M_1(\Sigma)$ be the probability simplex in $\mathbb{R}^{|\Sigma|}$. Let $\mathbb{P}_\mu$ denote the probability law $\mu^{\mathbb{Z}^+}$ associated with an infinite sequence of i.i.d. random variables $\{Y_j\}$ distributed following $\mu \in M_1(\Sigma)$.
For every set $\Gamma$ of probability vectors in $M_1(\Sigma)$,
$- \inf_{\nu \in \Gamma^\circ} H(\nu|\mu) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \mathbb{P}_\mu(L_n^Y \in \Gamma)
\leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \mathbb{P}_\mu(L_n^Y \in \Gamma) \leq - \inf_{\nu \in \Gamma} H(\nu|\mu)$,
where $\Gamma^\circ$ is the interior of $\Gamma$ considered as a subset of $M_1(\Sigma)$.
Then, in the remark, the authors mentioned that the closure operation in the closure operation is unnecessary in this case. But I don't really understand why there is no need for the closure operation here. My guess is that it might has something to do with probability simplex being compact, but I am not sure.
Any insight will be appreciated! :)
